# Concrete5: User Attributes vs Custom DB-Table, what are the Pros and Cons?

Tags: php, database-design, concrete5

I'm developing a page with C5 needing various data to be attached to the user accounts. There are two types of users, having different data. Some of the data is multi dimensional and therefor needs custom DB tables. My question is now if it makes sense to store all data in custom DB tables or to use user attributes for the one dimensional data.

Probably there is no general answer to this, but maybe some pros and cons?

I'm often asking myself where to store data in Concrete5 and would be interested how others decide ...

Comment: One pro for attributes I already discovered: They are visible, searchable and exportable via the dashboard. Probably helpful for the user management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. I'd definitely store as user attributes for similar reasons to the one you've already identified (visible, searchable, etc).

concrete5 is extensible, but not ***super*** extensible; you can attach data to a user using attributes, but not through some totally custom object / db table that you also expect to, e.g., show up on the user profile page.

Oftentimes in c5 (like any other framework), doing it the Right way (attribute) is more difficult (especially for the first "object", but also for each additional one) than just creating a db table and linking to a user id. But, like in all frameworks, you'll reap benefits down the road that you hadn't even considered. This is in searching, upgradability, and things that might only occur to the guy who takes over development next year.

So, with all that being said, go with attributes. And not just for the one dimensional data. You can configure the attribute controller (and the db schema behind it) to store any data you wish. Look at the Address attribute. This contains multiple fields (though it's still 1D). I think there's an opensource "multi address" attribute out there which stores 1-n addresses as a single attribute. You can do this with an additional linked table, but I've recently gotten lazy with c5 and done no-mysql by dumping `json_encode()`ed (multi-dimensional) arrays in the "data" field. (In this case, your attribute doesn't even need its own table -- it can use the Default table.) You can then configure the editing interface and also the display value (so, e.g., it just shows a list of each sub-object's `Name` property). Similarly, you can configure the text that gets indexed for searching purposes.

You asked for pros/cons. Doing this custom will be quicker and more straightforward. Extending an attribute, especially to create something complex, isn't super simple, and there isn't a lot of good documentation. Also, the attribute-editing UI (on the user dashboard page) is a bit kludgy. Yes, you get to "design" whatever you want within the "table cell", but you're still limited to making the admin click on the attribute name, using your editing interface within the cell, and then (ideally) clicking on the little disk icon. (Creating a javascript dialog might solve some issues here.)

Comment: thanks for your informative answer! will add some thoughts next week.

Comment: This is a great answer! I have some starter code for building custom attributes -- might help you make more sense of it (as with most advanced things in C5, attributes are woefully under-documented): http://c5blog.jordanlev.com/blog/2012/03/minimal-attribute-type-code/

Comment: thanks again james, your answer was very helpfull. i put all 1d-data in attributes, which feels very right! unfortunatly i didn't have the chance to experiment with custom attribute types cause the deadline is to short.

Comment: And two other pro's for custom tables: 1. it offers more freedom for querying the data with sql-statements ... while I haven't checked the ItemList model in detail which offers functions for custom queries as well. 2. It's easier to release the bounding between users and data, if neccessary one day.

Comment: The ItemList is quite advanced, except for OR clauses, but you can always add manual SQL. Note, though, that you wouldn't be querying against an ItemList of attributes, but a UserList, and individual indexed attribute values on Users.